# weighted version of wilcox.test in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I would like to compare my data to see if the means are different. The data is not normal so I am using a wilcox rank sum test to test for difference distributions.

I would like to incorporate a weight vector that for each group sums up to 1.

Is there a version of the wilcox test that allows for weights?

Thank you.

Comment: It's perverse of R to use an abbreviated name here. The test is due to (Frank) Wilcoxon. (It's a bizarre coincidence that he did write one paper with a Wilcox.) On the weights: it seems to me that you can use any kind of weight that is compatible with ranking. For example, if (say) 42 occurs 3 times, meaning that your data come as values and frequencies, then expand the data before ranking. What other kind of weights are compatible with ranking? How to do this in R is off-topic here.

Comment: The weights are not frequencies. But dollar values. For higher dollar observations I'd like to weight them more either using the dollar amount itself or the % of total dollar amount that observation is in the group.

Comment: I am fuzzy on what the data are, but you can always calculate value $\times$ weight and push that through the test as the variable of interest. But if your original data are in dollars, then it's exactly the same test in that circumstance!   The ranking of values on dollar$^2$ is precisely the same as that on dollars. Also, the same applies to dollar $\times$ % of total.

Comment: the original data is not in dollars. the wilcoxon test does not have  parameter for weights.

Comment: I think you mean that the R implementation does not allow weights. But that should not matter. If your variable of interest is something $\times$ weight, calculate that first and then feed it to the routine. (I don't know what other interpretation weights could have here. Nor do I think your test has a clear interpretation except in terms of the new variable.)

Comment: How do the weights arise? Note that the wilcoxon test is neither a test for medians nor means. If you actually want to test means, why not actually test means either with a nonparametric test, or with a more suitable parametric assumption?

Comment: Glen you are right the wilcoxon is used to  test the hypothesis that the distribution of X-measurements in
population A is the same as that in B.  The weights are just dollar values. Imagine you compare the time on days of market for a house of 2 groups in days and the weights are the house price.

Comment: That sounds like you are describing a *covariate,* not a weight. We might have a miscommunication problem due to differences in understanding the terminology.  Could you back up a little and explain how these "dollar values" need to function in your modeling or testing and also articulate more precisely what you are trying to test?

Comment: Let's say you have a score to measure real estate brokers and you want to test if the score is different between 2 groups but you want to put more weight on scores that had a higher housing price in dollar value. Imagine looking at the housing price weighted score for hte 2 groups but that asking is the difference in score statistically significant. You can run a t test on the unweighted score but it does not  account for hte price of the house.